# Submodule of a free module over a principal ring

Tags: modules, free-modules

I'm looking a counterexample.

> A free module over a principal ring such that it exists a submodule
>   which is not free. (Of course it's impossible when the module is
>   finitely generated).

Thanks and regards.

EDIT: The main problem I have is to prove that $Z^{N}$ or $Z_{2}^{N}$ are free. Otherwise I think they could be a good couterexemple. Maybe it's possible to find easier solution.

Comment: By ‘principal ring’, I suppose you mean P.I.D. (i.e. an integral domain)?

Comment: Yes i meant PID

Comment: The main problem I have is to prove that $Z^{N}$ or $Z_{2}^{N}$ are free. Otherwise I think they could be a good couterexemple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find such a counterexample since it is a direct consequence of the following theorem:

> Let $A$ be a ring such that every left ideal is projective. Every submodule $M$ of a free left $A$-module $L$ is a direct sum of modules  isomorphic to ideals of $A$.

(Bourbaki, *Algebra*, ch.7, *Modules over Principal Ideal Domains*, §3 theorem 1).

Another consequence is that a submodule of a projective module over a Dedekind domain is projective.

Comment: Okay do you have a counter exemple over a integral ring ?

Comment: What do you call an integral ring?

Comment: Integral domain

Comment: So you mean a counterexample with an integral domain such that ideals are not necessarily projective?

Comment: I don't know what is a projective module ^^.

Comment: For exemple $K[X,Y]$ is a counter exemple of a free module such as every submodule is free. Considerating the submodule $(X,Y)$. So it's natural to ask can we fin a counter exemple with the condition that the module is not finitly generated. You already answer over the PID, thank you. Now what is it's just a integral domain.

Comment: To simplify, a projective module is a direct summand of a free module.

Comment: You can expand to the ring $K[X_n]_{n\in\mathbf N}$ and the maximal ideal $(X_1\dots,X_n,\dots)$

Comment: Because you have (obvious) linear relations between the generators; $X_iX_j-X_jX_i=0$